# Get value for data-title not the name but the integer value being updated

Tags: html, jquery, rating-system

I am using this [rating widget](https://rating-widget.com/) and I want to get the value for my star rating like 1 star or 2 stars so I can manipulate the image being shown. I want to get the value from the `data-title` not the name I stored for it.

`data-title="stack"`

which holds a 5 star rating. I want it to return 5 or 5 star on my console and not just `stack`.

This will give output `Grey / Silver`
But I want the integer value stored for it.
Is there any way I can achieve that ?

```js
var data = $('.color-box').data('title');
console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="value">
  <div class="color-box grey-silver-color-gradient" data-title="Grey / Silver" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="" title=""></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: Please check again

Comment: How should we know how to get the integer value  stored? Your code in the snippet I made, does not show what the original value is

Comment: @mplungjan I am using that website so I am using ```<div class="rw-ui-container bc-rate" data-title="beliz bc rating"></div>``` which is being updated on every rating I get, I need that value.

Comment: I still do not see any integer. Please click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and post a ***[mcve]***

Comment: Please check [this](https://bravovince.netlify.app/bb.html), and hover on the images, there is a rating behind there. Can I change the image based on the rating. getting the actual value for ```data-title``` and not the name I gave it. Sorry I could not give it a minimal reproducible example @mplungjan

Comment: And how do I see the data-title with an int? Your data-title are on the format `data-title="skyler bb rating"`

Comment: Yes, Can I pick the star rating which I believe is being stored by the widget I am using? Each card has a different ```data-title``` storing rating for each. This clears out anything?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```js
console.log($("[data-title^=walter]").find(".rw-ui-star-selected").length)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
  <div class="card__side card__side--front card__side--front-1">
    <div class="card__description">
      <img src="images/Walter_White_S5B.png" class="imgcard">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card__side card__side--back card__side--back-bb">
    <div class="card__description">
      <p class="text-title drop drop-top">Bryan Cranston</p>
      <p class="text-small pad-small drop">As</p>
      <p class="text-title drop">Walter H. White</p>
      <p class="text-small pad-small drop">A.K.A.</p>
      <p class="text-title drop">Heisenberg,<br> Mr. Lambert,<br> Mr. Mayhew<br></p>
      <p class="text-small drop"><q>I am the one who knocks.</q></p>
      <p class="text-small drop"><q>Say my name.</q></p>
      <p class="text-small"><q>All right, I've got the talking pillow now.</q></p>
      <!-- <div class="rw-ui-container" data-title="walter bb rating"></div> -->
    </div>
    <div class="rater">
      <div class="rw-ui-container rw-urid-17803414863255154888 rw-ui-star rw-size-medium rw-dir-ltr rw-halign-center rw-valign-bottom rw-style-oxygen1 rw-active" data-title="walter bb rating" data-urid="walter bb rating" style="">
        <div class="rw-action-area">
          <ul class="rw-ui-stars">
            <li class="rw-ui-star-0 rw-ui-star-selected"></li>
            <li class="rw-ui-star-1 rw-ui-star-selected"></li>
            <li class="rw-ui-star-2 rw-ui-star-selected"></li>
            <li class="rw-ui-star-3"></li>
            <li class="rw-ui-star-4"></li>
          </ul>
          <a class="rw-report-link" target="_blank" href="https://rating-widget.com/my-rating-report/star/oxygen1/rating-0-5/" rel="nofollow"></a>
        </div><span class="rw-ui-info-container" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><i aria-hidden="true" class="rw-ui-info-nub rw-ui-info-outer-nub" style="border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);"></i><i aria-hidden="true" class="rw-ui-info-nub rw-ui-info-inner-nub" style="border-bottom-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></i><span class="rw-ui-info-inner-container" style="border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);"><span class="rw-ui-info" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">Rate this</span></span>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, just like this, if I can get what the average is at that moment. Is that possible?

Comment: Average of what? I have to pull every single bit of info out of you word by word, don't I ? ;)

Comment: The average of the star rating at the moment. The rating which is being displayed there, sorry I thought that was obvious. Like the code you sent shows only 3 as you have selected three stars. So when in real time and people keep voting and the average keeps changing. To keep getting the average so I keep changing the image to be displayed.

Comment: It is not obvious. Unless the widget is updated in real time by the server, you would have to ajax to the server to see what the others have been rating

Comment: Okay, my bad. So can I get the average of whatever the last value updated can be picked?

Comment: What is the average of one value?

Comment: hahahahahaha, When there have been a few ratings given, and the avg is say 4, can I get that? It dosent matter if it was 4 an hour ago and has changed to say 3 due to more users voting.

Comment: I have no idea how to get that without getting the widget, reading the documentation, see if there is some kind of stats functionality... You are on one page. If you reload, do the stars change if someone else in the world voted?

Comment: Yes, the stars change, I went through their website but couldnt get any thing worthwhile, I cant even get to remove the i icon next to the stars. They have an option to make some changes but thats it I guess.

Comment: So if the stars change, the average is what you see on the screen, and what I gave you in the script above, no?

Comment: Yes, the script you gave gives 3 in console no matter what.

Comment: In MY script you get 3 because I do not have the widget installed!!! I HARDCODED 3 selected

Comment: Even I am getting 3, please help. Yes I tried removing that, then I was getting zero